# Phaser3 and Typescript - Extends SpriteWithDynamicBody

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I'd like to create a class hero that extends from `SpriteWithDynamicBody` but I can't since `SpriteWithDynamicBody` is only declared as a type (and we can't extend from a type in typescript)

I can only extends `Sprite` but then, some methods/properties are not available:

```js
export class Hero extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
    constructor(public scene: Phaser.Scene, x: number, y: number, texture: string, frame?: number) {
        super(scene, x, y, texture, frame);
        this.setVelocity(0); // => Error
    }
}
```

What can I do to extend `SpriteWithDynamicBody` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend from the class `Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite`, if you need to create a custom Sprite with a *dynamicBody / (physics body)* , this should have all the properties/features you are looking for. [Link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite.html)

Here is a [link to a comprehensive demo](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/physics/arcade/extending-arcade-sprite) from the official website, that showcases this.